# Calculate EER from FAR and FRR?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, roc

I'm wondering if we have FAR and FRR scores for each threshold if we can compute an EER programatically?

Say we have:

```
FAR FRR
1.0 0.0
0.8 0.1
0.6 0.2
0.5 0.4
0.2 0.6
0.0 1.0
```

Can we compute the EER programatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can compute the `EER` from the `FAR` and `FRR`. Usually, the `EER` is just the error for `FAR==FRR`. In case there is no numeric value `FAR==FRR` (like in your provided example), you need to take a value in between the closest `FAR` and `FRR` values. There are multiple ways of obtaining such (none of them is perfect, as the information you seek is missing by definititon, so you can just get a close estimate). I've seen e.g.

- $EER=\frac{FAR+FRR}{2}$ with those single `FAR` and `FRR` values that minimize `abs(FAR-FRR)`. In your case: $\frac{0.5+0.4}{2} = 0.45$.
- Using the line between the `FAR` and `FRR` values directly before and after `FAR==FRR` (in your case: the line between `FAR1=0.5`, `FRR1=0.4`, and `FPR2=0.2`, `FRR2=0.6`). The intersection of this line with the line `[1,1]` to `[0,0]` is frequently used as EER too.

Just for completeness: from my understanding, both approximations are necessarily very slightly pessimistic, as they do a linear approximation over a non-linear relation, towards more error.

Comment: That's very helpful! Thank you. Do you have a link for where you learnt this so I can learn more? I understand this method, I thought it was the case but it seems weird to use an EER that's an average because the gap between the closest FAR and FRR could (in theory!) be huge!

Comment: @mino Usually, if you have a large amount of samples, this problem with become rather small and unimportant, as predicted class probabilities likely differ amongst samples. An exception are cases where many samples yield *exactly* the same class probabilities (and you overall just have a small amount of different class probabilities predicted for all samples) - but in such case I would try to find out why this happens, because this could indicate other and much bigger problems. For the link: I don't have one at hand, but try searching here on CV or in one of the classic ML books.